# Rank mismatch in fortran

Tags: fortran, rank, mismatch

when executing this function:

```
FUNCTION gaussian_elimination(A, C) result(X)
implicit none
real, intent(inout) :: C(:), A(size(C), size(C))
real :: X(size(C))

real    :: D(size(C))
integer :: i, j, neq

neq = size(C)

! Forward reduction, only two loops since reduction is now row by row
do i = 1, neq
D = A(:,i)/A(i,i)

do j = i+1, neq
A(j,:) = A(j,:) - D(j)*A(i,:)
C(j) = C(j) - D(j)*C(i)
enddo
enddo

! Back substitution, only one loop
do i = neq, 1, -1
x(i) = (C(i) - sum(A(i, i+1:) * x(i+1:))) / A(i,i)
enddo

end FUNCTION gaussian_elimination
```

With the following:

```
real , DIMENSION(6,6) :: K
real , DIMENSION(6,1) :: R
real , DIMENSION(6,1) :: n
n = gaussian_elimination(K,R)
```

Result:

```
n = gaussian_elimination(K,R)
1
```

Error: Incompatible ranks 2 and 1 in assignment at (1)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a second dimension to `X` if `n` should be of `DIMENSION(6,1)`:

```
real :: X(size(C,1),size(C,2))
```

Note, that you additionally have the dummy arguments specified wrong... It should probably read:

```
FUNCTION gaussian_elimination(A, C) result(X)
implicit none
real, intent(inout) :: C(:,:), A(size(C,1), size(C,1))
real :: X(size(C,1),size(C,2))
...
```

---

Alternatively, you could define `R` and `n` as

```
real , DIMENSION(6) :: R
real , DIMENSION(6) :: n
```

and leave your code unchanged.

---

Option three: You work with array slices:

```
n(:,1) = gaussian_elimination(K,R(:,1))
```

No changes in the code...